# Error writing result to store for query. Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm getting an error when writing a query to store after a mutation. The mutation works and i'm able to read the query post mutation. When i write the same query to the store cache i get the following Error:

```
index.js:2178 Error: Error writing result to store for query:
 query ($applicationId: Int) {
  vApplicationApprovalChainList(ApplicationId: $applicationId) {
    id
    approvalOrder
    approverId
    name
    applicationId
    __typename
  }
}

Cannot read property 'vApplicationApprovalChainList' of undefined
    at writeToStore.js:101
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at writeSelectionSetToStore (writeToStore.js:97)
    at writeResultToStore (writeToStore.js:75)
    at InMemoryCache../node_modules/apollo-cache-inmemory/lib/inMemoryCache.js.InMemoryCache.write (inMemoryCache.js:99)
```

Here is my code.. the mutation and `store.readQuery` works but the `store.writeQuery` gives above error. Thank you in advance for any feedback.

```
APPROVERSLIST_QUERY = gql`
query ($applicationId:Int){
 vApplicationApprovalChainList(ApplicationId:$applicationId){
  id
  approvalOrder
  approverId  
  name
  applicationId  

  }
}

`;


 handleClick() {
        const { row, mutate} = this.props;
        mutate({
            variables: {
                id: row.id
            },
            update: (store, { data: { deleteApprover } }) => {

                const newdata = store.readQuery({
                    query: APPROVERSLIST_QUERY,
                    variables: { applicationId: row.applicationId }
                });
                console.log(newdata);
                newdata.vApplicationApprovalChainList = newdata.vApplicationApprovalChainList.filter(approver => approver.id !== deleteApprover.id);
                store.writeQuery({
                    query: APPROVERSLIST_QUERY, newdata });
                }
        });



    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not passing in the new data to `writeQuery`. The object passed to `writeQuery` must have a property named `data` containing the new data. Additionally, since your query contains variables, you will need to include that information as well.

```
store.writeQuery({
  query: APPROVERSLIST_QUERY,
  data: newdata,
  variables: {
    applicationId: row.applicationId,
  },
});
```

Please see [the official docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html) for more examples and a more thorough explanation of the two methods.

Comment: I have spent 4 hours hitting a wall with this. Thank you So much for answering this!!